# gitlab-ci with Golang do not create the right folder structure

Tags: go, gitlab, gitlab-ci

Having a Golang project and Go workspace. I'm trying to run my test, but I'm having the following error :

```
api/server.go:8:2: cannot find package "github.com/braintree/manners" in any of:
    /usr/local/go/src/github.com/braintree/manners (from $GOROOT)
    /go/src/github.com/braintree/manners (from $GOPATH)
```

The problem comes from that when cloning the project it does it in this folder :

Cloning into '/builds/compagny/project'...

```
$GOPATH is /go
```

and then inside that folder I should have something like : `src/github.com/compagny/project`

I can : `export GOPATH=$(pwd)`, but that doesn't help, Go expect a /src folder.

But I do not have the control where gitlab-ci clone the project, do I?

my gitlab-ci.yml :

```
stages:
  - build
  - test

build-my-project:
  image: golang:1.6
  stage: build
  script:
    - go get -u github.com/Masterminds/glide
    - glide install
    - go build

test-my-project:
  image: golang:1.6
  stage: test
  script:
    - go get -u github.com/Masterminds/glide
    - glide install
    - go test -v ./...
```

Comment: You have to run `go get ...` to load the dependencies of the project.

Comment: @mgansler glide does that work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the go wrapper provided in the image instead of glide. It will create a symlink in the proper location and then `go get` your dependencies. E.g.

```
build-my-project:
  image: golang:1.6
  stage: build
  script:
    - go-wrapper download
    - go build
```

So the go wrapper knows the proper path of your project you will need to add it as an import comment in your `main.go` like so:

```
package main // import "github.com/your/repo"
```

Answer (score 0):

For workaround, you can copy cloned project to GOPATH folder.

```
    script :
    - mv /builds/ $GOPATH/src/github.com/company/project
```